# Applying for a long-term visa while you are in the country with a Schengen Visa?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, eu

As a non-EU national, can you apply for a long-term D-type German visa while you are in Germany with a Schengen visa?

Note: I am a Turkish national.

Comment: That question is not on topic here, but belongs on expatriates stack exchange. The answer depends on your citizenship, so if you ask the question there, you must  be more specific.

Comment: To the extent that you are allowed to apply from within the country, you would typically apply for a residence permit directly and skip the visa step.

Comment: @Relaxed the visa processing times for different visas are different, so in practice that is definitely not the case.

Comment: @onurcanbektas What is not the case? I fail to see the connection to the point I was making.

Comment: @Relaxed What I mean is the visa processing time for those visas are different, which makes what you said unattractive because in practive you might not be able to wait long.

Comment: @Relaxed So, if I go to Germany with a Schengen visa, can I apply for a Residence permit within the country? (and that would make me eligible to live there?)

Comment: @Relaxed if indeed I can do that, that would be terrific!

Comment: Probably not, you can refer to Mark's answer. My point was simply that *if* you are allowed to secure long-term residence from within the country, it would most likely be by applying for a residence permit, not a visa. I still don't understand your point about different visa processing times, I wasn't talking about different visas at all. Note that some things are inconvenient by design, there isn't always a way to go around long visa processing times, etc.

Comment: When a D-Visa is applied for, with the goal of getting a residence permit, then these applications are sent to and desided in Germany - thus they take longer. In general all C-Visas and some D-Visas can be desided by the consulate directly and thus the processing time is faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, as a general rule 3rd country citizens that require a **residence permit** for long term visits (longer than 3 months), must apply for a D-Visa at the 'competent mission' (mostly based on your main place of residence).

Exceptions exist for the citizens of the following countries:

- USA
- Canada
- Australia
- Japan
- Israel
- New Zealand
- South Korea

who may apply after their arrival in Germany.

---

**Sources**:

- [Visa regulations - Federal Foreign Office](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/visabestimmungen-node)

Comment: (+1) Another exception are spouses of EU citizens who may always apply for a residence card (not a permit) after entering the country.